# Only one component shows up in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

As an improvement to my encryption project I decided to make a little GUI. However, when I run the program, only the top element shows up on the screen and it appears to obscure the others, though I have no way of checking. Does anyone know why? 
Below is my code in its entirety besides `e()` and `d()` because those simply encrypt a string and have nothing to do with a GUI. I would also like a way to speed it up as much as possible without editing the encryption, just to make it as great as possbile.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EncDecExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    final static JPanel top = new JPanel();
    final static JPanel mid = new JPanel();
    final static JPanel bot = new JPanel();
    final static JTextField in = new JTextField(10);
    final static JTextField out = new JTextField(10);
    final static JButton enc = new JButton("Encrypt");
    final static JButton dec = new JButton("Decrypt");
    final static JFrame f = new JFrame("Encryption/decryption");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        EncDec.exampleImplement();

        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        out.setEditable(false);
        out.setText("Hello");
        in.setVisible(true);
        out.setVisible(true);
        enc.setVisible(true);
        dec.setVisible(true);
        top.add(in);
        mid.add(enc);
        mid.add(dec);
        bot.add(out);
        f.add(top);
        f.add(mid);
        f.add(bot);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == enc && !in.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            out.setText(EncDec.e(in.getText(), 5));
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == dec && !in.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            out.setText(EncDec.d(in.getText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) may interest you.

Comment: @Pshemo I looked at it before asking my question, and it doesn't seem to work. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The content pane of a `JFrame` has a `BorderLayout`.  If you place a component in a BL with no constraints it ends up in the `CENTER`.  The center can only display one component.

For an immediate effect, I suggest:

```
f.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
f.add(mid);
f.add(bot, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

### Other points.

1. Take out `f.setSize(500, 500);` and call `pack()` immediately before `setVisible(true)`
2. For a better way to end the GUI, change `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` to `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`
3. `in.setVisible(true);` Except for the frame itself, take these out.  A component automatically becomes visible when it is added to a top level container and that container is itself made visible.
4. Change 
   `public class EncDecExample extends JFrame` 
   to 
   `public class EncDecExample`
     This code keeps a reference to a frame, and that is the right way to go.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was wondering if I needed to extend JFrame because I saw it like that on a tutorial I saw before posting the question, but it didn't make sense. Great answer, by the way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any other layout I can use so I do not have to add the `BorderLayout.LAYOUT` bit?

Comment: Yes there are various layouts.  Certainly `FlowLayout` and `GridLayout` with the right constructor.  But I am a bit suspicious of this "so I do not have to" stuff.  It will end up producing an horrid GUI.

Comment: I can see why you would be susicious... It just helps with code readability (Is that a word?) and so I can know more about the language.

Comment: @NickHartley _It just helps with code readability_ that is no reason to choose an inappropriate layout and provide a poor user experience. `FlowLayout` and `GridLayout` are, IMHO, very poor LayoutManagers and are useful in very few situations. `BorderLayout` and `GridBagLayout` are a lot better.

Comment: See, this is what I mean by "I want to know more about the language" - I have never seen any of this before (My first time doing GUIs) and I didn't know what would be good and what wouldn't. :)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet *"..`GridLayout` are, IMHO, very poor LayoutManagers and are useful in very few situations."*  I'm shocked you would say that. I can only presume, from that comment, that you do *not* code a bunch of trivial board games like Mine Sweeper.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson ... No, I usually have complex graphical UI with many components, nested layouts etc... One of the few situations where I like to use `GridLayout` is when I display several buttons in a Dialog. :-)