# Buttons do not seem to respond when pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border-layout

Again, hello everyone. I'm having more trouble with my encryption code - The button presses don't seem to be registering. The code to detect the button presses is below.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == enc && !in.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        out.setText(EncDec.e(in.getText(), 5));
        System.out.println("Button pressed (Encrypt)");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == dec && !in.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        out.setText(EncDec.d(in.getText()));
        System.out.println("Button pressed (Decrypt)");
    }
}
```

This question is indeed related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/solved-only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe), and thanks to Pshemo for letting me know :)
I have the `System.out.println()` to tell me when a button is pressed, and nothing is printed to console when I press either of the buttons named below. If you need more information, just ask and I will be happy to add it. 
I tried adding `addActionListener()` to the code, but I don't know how to use it...

Comment: Could you show us how you set this code to be executed when you press Button?

Comment: @Pshemo Hey, didn't I jsut see you a second ago? :) But the code is all there. The things inside the if statements.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   The only WAG I can come up with based on the snippet is that you forgot to add the listener to the button.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You seem to be in agreement with the person who just answered the question... As I said, I'll do that then post my results.

Comment: @NickHartley If you marked some answer as solution then there is no need to add "SOLVED!" to title of question. After acceptation answer number of answers in question will turn yellow which means that problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/solved-only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe).

All you need to do is to add object of your class (that implements `ActionListener`) with `addActionListener` to your Buttons, like:

```
EncDecExample decExample = new EncDecExample();
enc.addActionListener(decExample);
dec.addActionListener(decExample);
enc.setVisible(true);
dec.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You are correct in that the question is related to my other one. Sorry I should post a link to it. And thanks a TON for letting me know what to add for the ActionListener... I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: @NickHartley btw, no need to call `setVisible(true)` on `JComponent`, they are visible by default. You only need to call `setVisible(true)` on `JDialog`'s and `JFrame`'s.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet You may want to comment on my original question, I will likely see it faster because it's on the top of the page instead of in the middle. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @NickHartley When I send a message, you automatically get a red baloon at the top of the page, wherever I post my comment ;-)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Not only him :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting a logging statement before either of the conditions get evaluated to see if the ActionEvent is in fact even triggering properly.   If it is, try outputting the source of the action to make sure that the proper button is being pressed.

Otherwise, I'd first check to see if your two buttons are registering the addition of the actionListener...."enc.addActionListener();".

If that looks good, I'd try putting a try/catch around the setText lines to see if the "EncDec.e" or "EncDec.d" are throwing Exceptions of some kind.

Some stuff to try anyway!  :)

Comment: I just did add the code before any `if` statements - I suppose I should update my code now, shouldn't I? Also, I know from experience that e() and d() do not throw exceptions, all they do is change a line of text into another line of text. The `enc.addActionListener()` may be helpful, though... I'll try it and post my results.