# How to add a JPanel to a JFrame Ten Times

Tags: java, swing

My goal is to create a random car or truck ten times which should have a random position. When I try adding numerous JPanels to my JFrame only one appears to show up. How can I call the method randomVehicle() to draw more than just one Vehicle at a time, I've tried adding print statements and checking my logic over but I'm at a loss.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GraphicsTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1. Create the frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //4. Size the frame.
        frame.setSize(2000, 2000);
        //5. Show it.

        Vehicle frame1 = new Vehicle();
        frame.add(frame1.randomVehicle());
        frame.add(frame1.randomVehicle());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Vehicle class

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Vehicle extends JPanel {

    public Vehicle() {
    xPos = (int) (Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    yPos = (int) (Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    }

    public Vehicle randomVehicle() {
        int vehicleRandom = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        System.out.println(vehicleRandom);
        if (vehicleRandom==1) {
            return new Car();
        }
        if (vehicleRandom==2) {
            return new Truck();
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected int xPos;
    protected int yPos;

}
```

Car

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Car extends Vehicle {

    public Car() {
        super();
        System.out.println(xPos);
        System.out.println(yPos);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle(xPos + 100, yPos + 100, 200, 50));
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle(xPos + 150, yPos + 85, 100, 15));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 120, yPos + 150, 50, 35));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 220, yPos + 150, 50, 35));
    }

}
```

Truck

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    public Truck() {
        super();
        System.out.println(xPos);
        System.out.println(yPos);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle(xPos + 100, yPos + 100, 50, 75));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 110, yPos + 175, 35, 35));
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle(xPos + 180, yPos + 70, 350, 106));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 190, yPos + 175, 35, 35));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 225, yPos + 175, 35, 35));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 475, yPos + 175, 35, 35));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos + 440, yPos + 175, 35, 35));
    }

}
```

Comment: *`public class Vehicle extends JPanel { ..`* I'd go with custom painting for this. So `Vehicle` should not extend `JPanel`, but instead declare a `public abstract void draw(Graphics);` method that `Car` and `Truck` need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop.. like below..

```
Vehicle frame1 = new Vehicle();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
frame.add(frame1.randomVehicle());
}

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I've tried that, the problem is that only one vehicle is drawn even though the method is called 10 times.

Comment: it is because the second component is adding on top of the first component.. refer this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe