# i'm trying to creat multiple jbuttons in jframe using for loop

Tags: java

i wrote this code for creating jbuttons in a jframe i have already created

```
String m=profile.jTextField6.getText();
     int M = Integer.parseInt(m);

     تنشيفT f1 = new تنشيفT();
     f1. setVisible(true);
     f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        JButton btnBoard = new JButton("month  "+ +i);
        f1.add(btnBoard);
        btnBoard.setSize(500, 100);
        btnBoard.setLocation((50+(15*M)), (100+(15*M)));


     }
```

every time i click the button i found only one button created with month 0 inside it 
help me please;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I'm going to guess here (for us to not have to guess post a valid [mcve]). 1) You create a `JFrame` (I don't know what `تنشيفT` means or how that class looks like, but I'm guessing it's a `JFrame`, so, it has a `BorderLayout` by default and thus this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe). You need to learn to use the [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). 2) You're calling `setVisible(true)` before adding the components to it, that should be the last line in your program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only one component shows up in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help , the code was ok it was the layout manager where i was willing to export the buttons , when i set it to box layout it created the whole buttons

```
if (profile.jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("تخسيس")){
  تخسيسT f2 = new تخسيسT();
  String m=profile.jTextField6.getText();
     int M = Integer.parseInt(m);
     for ( int i = 1; i <= M; i++ ){

        JButton btn = new JButton("month  "+ +i);

        f2.add(btn);
        btn.setSize(500, 100);
        btn.setLocation(0, 0);
        f2.setSize(85*M, 150);
     }
     f2. setVisible(true);
     f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

  }
```