# Painting Panels in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, graphics2d

So I'm trying to paint multiple Panels at the same time. First, I have the abstract class whose instances I seek to paint:

```
public abstract class GameObject extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double velX;
    public double velY;
    public Dimension dim;
    public abstract void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e);
}
```

Then the child:

```
public class Ball extends GameObject implements ActionListener
{
    public final double DEF_X = 0;
    public final double DEF_Y = 0;
    public final double DEFAULT_SIZE = 20;

    public Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

    public Ball (int aVelocity)
    {
        x = DEF_X;
        y = DEF_Y;
        velX = aVelocity;
        velY = aVelocity;
        dim = new Dimension((int) DEFAULT_SIZE, (int) DEFAULT_SIZE);

        t.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, dim.getWidth(), dim.getHeight());
        g2.fill(circle);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 560)
        {
            velX = -velX;
        }
        if (y < 0 || y > 360)
        {
            velY = -velY;
        }

        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        repaint();
    }
}
```

So in the driver I want 2 instances of Ball to be moving at the same time. After making two balls, I've tried adding both to a JFrame, but only one will paint. I've tried adding both balls to a main JPanel p, and then added p to my JFrame, but this didn't paint either of them.

```
public class Game
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        Ball b1 = new Ball(5);
        Ball b2 = new Ball(10);

        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        f.add(p);
        // I also tried just doing f.add(b1) and f.add(b2), but those only display 1 ball.

        f.setSize(620, 440);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        f.setLocation(dim.width/2-f.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-f.getSize().height/2);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So what can I do to remedy this and have both balls painted at the same time?

Comment: *"I've tried adding both to a JFrame, but only one will paint."* See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881444/only-one-component-shows-up-in-jframe/13881481#13881481) for an explanation. The upshot is, don't define a custom component that paints a single graphics element, instead define (non component) classes that know how to draw themselves, then make a single custom painted component that iterates a collection of the custom painted objects and paints each in turn.

Comment: I ended up making a single JComponent child that has each GameObject, and GameObject doesn't extend anything. This worked perfectly. Thanks!