# Button covering window

Tags: java, swing, button, size

I'm very new to java and I now know how to make an empty window but there's a button and a label and the button keeps on covering the window. How do I size the button?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class swingProgram {
    
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JLabel label;
    private static JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
        button = new JButton();
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        
        
        label = new JLabel("Hello Window!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(button);

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that the code is trying to put two components, in a place only one can go. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Other notes: 1) `frame.setVisible(true);` should be last. Immediately after `frame.pack();` 2) All Swing/AWT GUIs should be made and launched on the Event Dispatch Thread. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 4) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881481/418556) to *"Only one component shows up in JFrame"* for more details re the 1st comment. 5) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. ..

Comment: .. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 5) The button and frame can accept text in the constructor. It is used as the title of the frame or text of the button. You might instead pass an `ImageIcon` to the button constructor.

Comment: Also, don't use static variables.

Comment: @AndrewThompson can you please simplify what you said pls?

Comment: What don't you understand? Be specific.

Comment: since im a beginner, i would say, everything? except for the ```frame.setVisible(true)``` after ```frame.pack()```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I forgot to add a GridLayout.

Answer (score -3):

You have to create the label first or add the label first
and add the label in frame
and add the button in label
and set the button properties to these
Here as you can notice, I have changed all the components properties
But first you must learn the swing components properties
Best of luck

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        label = new JLabel("Hello Window!");
        label.setSize(300,300);
        label.setLocation(50,50);
        label.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(label);

        
        button = new JButton();
        button.setSize(50,50);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setLocation(100,100);
        label.add(button);
   
    }

}
```

Comment: This code has (`label.setSize(300,300)` & `label.setVisible(true);`) redundant lines, (`label.add(button);`) poor hacks & (`frame.setVisible(true);`) code lines called at the wrong time. If you are looking for *good* example code, look elsewhere.